# mongodb - extract year from title

Tags: mongodb

I'm beginner in *Mongodb*. 
I'm working with MoviesLens dataset.

My collection have a field `'Title' = 'Toy Story (1995)'` for example.

I would like to obtain the following :

```
'Title' = 'Toy Story'
'Year' = '1995'
```

Somebody can help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that, in Mongo, you can use a fairly wide subset of Javascript standard library. The key is [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Say, your collections is called "movies". In Mongo CLI, you query it this way:

```
db.collection('movies').find();
```

Here, `find` returns a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/). This cursor supports a bunch of methods, and `map` is one of them. Map takes a function as the first argument, this function will be applied to every item of the cursor (in fact, it's a [very common functional pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function))). So, if you do this:

```
db.collection('movies').find().map(item => item);
```

then you'll end up with a collection of elements themselves, since

```
item => item
```

is a function that is applied with an item and returns item itself without changing it.

Now, you have `Title` property of item, and the value is a string that contains name of the movie and year, enclosed in round brackets. To deconstruct a string, you typically use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

You can see that a string "Toy Story (1995)" has a possible pattern: "%MOVIE% (%YEAR%)", where %MOVIE% is a sequence of letters, digits and possibly other characters (dash, etc.), while %YEAR% has to consist of digits exclusively. An appropriate regular expression would be

```
/^(.+)\s\((\d{4})\)$/
```

What you do next is you apply such a function in `map` that takes item and does two things:

1. Replaces value of "Title" property with just title, and
2. Adds "Year" property with proper value.

Should look like this:

```
db.collection('movies').find().map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {
  Title: /^(.+)\s\((\d{4})\)$/.match(item.Title)[1],
  Year: /^(.+)\s\((\d{4})\)$/.match(item.Title)[2]
}));
```

---

Please note that calling [`cursor.map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.map/) doesn't update items in the collection. To update them, use [`db.collection.update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).